# Changing Paintbox size and graphics problem

Tags: delphi, pascal

Whenever I change a paintbox's size, the paintbox simply clears itself and won't add any graphics in the same procedure.

Here's what I'm trying to do (BMP is a bitmap).

```
 PaintBox1.Width := PaintBox1.Width - 20;
 PaintBox1.Height := PaintBox1.Height - 20;
 BMP.Width := PaintBox1.Width;
 BMP.Height := PaintBox1.Height;
 Paintbox1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,BMP,255);
```

I've tried creating another procedure for drawing the bitmap and running this right after changing the paintbox's size, but this also doesn't work.

It only seems to work when I assign Canvas.Draw to another procedure and executing this afterwards with another button.

Any solutions?

Comment: That's the wrong way to use a paint box. Add an OnPaint event handler and paint there. You need to understand that painting to the screen is not persistent. Programs must do it on demand. OnPaint is that demand.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still new to the entire paintbox thing.When should I use canvas.draw then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing on-screen graphics is subject to repainting whenever Windows needs it to. The Windows messaging system sends a `WM_PAINT` message to a window handle when it requires painting to be done. In Delphi, in most cases, especially a `TPaintBox`, this means implementing the `OnPaint` event handler. This event is fired every time Windows needs you to do your painting.